# Stop loop function setTimeout

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I have a loop using setTimeout like bellow:

```
<button onclick="clickStop()">stop</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let i = 0;
    let sett;
    function timeOut(counter) {   
        sett = setTimeout(function () {
            $.get("./test3.php", {data_id: counter}, (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                i++;
                timeOut(i);
            });
        }, 1000);
        if(counter >= 10) {
            clearTimeout(sett);
            alert("Done!");
        }
    }
    timeOut(i);
    function clickStop() {
        clearTimeout(sett);
    }
</script>
```

But when i click button stop it's not working, help me!!

Comment: and what make you conclude that it is not working ?

Comment: I'm try and it's not working. ./test3.php takes 2 ~ 3 seconds to return results. When I press stop while. ./test3 in process, it will not work.

Comment: please be clear when you say *it's not working*. What is not working ?

Comment: This is going to be pretty fragile because if you cancel the timeout before the `$.get` returns, the callback will just start it again when it `$.get` call the callback. Maybe you could have `clickStop` set a flag that is checked before `$.get` calls the function.

Comment: So just a heads up, typically XHR calls should not be made in a loop. It can get expensive, or bad

Comment: What do I do to make it work? Customers will not know when it will return to press stop.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - it's not called in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the timeout and also set a flag that will alert the callback in `$.get` that it shouldn't call `timeOut()` when it returns:

```js
let i = 0;
let sett;
let active = true   // should the loop continue?
function timeOut(counter) {  
    if (counter < 10){
      sett = setTimeout(function () {
        $.get("./test3.php", {data_id: counter}, (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            i++;
            if (active) timeOut(i); // only if active
        });
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("Done!");
    }
}
timeOut(i);
function clickStop() {
    active = false      // stop loop
    clearTimeout(sett); // and clear current timeout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS seems to be working just fine, see below, the counter increments and stop when I click on the stop button. the issue is with `$.get("./test3.php" ...`

can you elaborate on what the expected response of the ajax call is?

Also if you can describe what you're trying to do, we can give you some pointers on best practices, because as those who commented have said, it's generally not a good idea to run XHR/ajax calls in loops

```html
<button onclick="clickStop()">stop</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let i = 0;
    let sett;
    function timeOut(counter) {   
        sett = setTimeout(function () {
            timeOut(counter+1);
            console.log(counter);
        }, 1000);
        if(counter >= 10) {
            clearTimeout(sett);
            alert("Done!");
        }
    }
    timeOut(i);
    function clickStop() {
        clearTimeout(sett);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `$ .get(" ./ test3.php "...` will take about 2 ~ 3 seconds to return results. How do I stop after clicking "stop" or when the last XHR calls finish?

Answer (score 0):

The `timeout(i)` you have inside the `$.get` response handler, would restart the loop even if you stopped it.
You can use a flag to get control over it.

```js
let i = 0;
let sett;
let status = true;
let url = "http://placekitten.com/200/300";

function timeOut(counter) {   
  sett = setTimeout(function () {
    $.get(url, (data) => {
      console.log(i);
      i++;
      // repeat if status flag is true
      if(status) timeOut(i);
    });
  }, 1000);
  
  if(counter >= 10) {
    clearTimeout(sett);
    status = false; // set status flag to false
    alert("Done!");
  }
}

function clickStop() {
    clearTimeout(sett);
    status = false; // set status flag to false
}

timeOut(i);
```

```html
<button onclick="clickStop()">stop</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```